# Displaying formatted text within a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, opengl-es

I have to create a UITableView, that contains richly formatted text within each UITableViewCell.

My first attempt at solving the problem was to convert the text to html and render the text within a UIWebView. However, I found that my cells were taking too long to load, and webviewdidload isn't called while scrolling. I then tried piecing together several formatted uilabels, but found that this method too caused performance issues.

I tried subclassing UITableViewCell and using CoreText drew NSAttributedStrings, however it is my understanding that CoreText is not available on devices with less than iOs 3.2, and I'd like my app to work on devices with ios 3.1.

I've heard that its also possible to use opengl es to render some formatted text, however this extends pretty far outside of my zone of experience.

Does anyone have any suggestions of simpler ways to approach this problem, or resources where I can learn more about rendering formatted text with opengl on iphone/ipad?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know there are multiple solutions out there but the one I know of and suggest you might look into is the Three20 library which includes TTStyledTextLabel.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This may be a silly question, but how do open source libraries like this work in the context of commercial applications? Are they free game for anyone? Or do I need to license with them or provide credits somewhere?

Comment: It depends on the license. Three20 uses the Apache License, Version 2.0.  Here is a S.O. entry that describes it's use in a commercial application: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007338/can-i-use-apache-software-license-2-0-lib-in-commercial-application